# Docker registry https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 34.200.90.16:443: giving Unauthorized

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am new to docker and using it on windows 7 64 bit.

When hitting the command `docker run hello-world` i getting below error

Error response from daemon: Get : dial tcp 34.200.90.16:443: connect: connection refused

`HTTP://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:` when i hit this url in browser i am getting UNAUTHORIZED.

[image]

I am not even able to login to docker through CLI as getting same error.

This are machines i have created in Docker.

[image]

I am in corporate proxy.
Sharing other details as,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set http_proxy in Docker.

Comment: And how we can do that sir??

Comment: If docker running under linux you can read this article https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Or on windows you need 
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port